# Full screen of div with DOJO

Tags: html, css, dojo

I have a div with a DOJO table. I want to display the div in full screen. I have tried using HTML5 API but the height and width are not enlarged in full screen mode. What are the other ways I can achieve a full screen with only the div containing DOJO table with it?? This is the table I have.

```
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid");
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Pagination");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Filter");
    dojo.require("dojox.data.QueryReadStore");
    dojo.require("dojo.parser"); // scan page for widgets and instantiate them
    var gridLayout = [ 
    {
            name : "Date & Time",
            classes : "title",
            field : "date",
            width : "140px"
    }, {
            name : 'Status',
            classes : "title",
            field : "statusMessage",
            fields : [ 'statusMessage', 'statusMessageColor' ],
            formatter : formatLink1,
            width : "140px"
    }];
```